# Firefox and Thunderbird crashing when opening File Explorer windows

Tags: windows-10, firefox, thunderbird

Ever since I installed a Windows 10 update two days ago, both Firefox and Thunderbird have been crashing every single time I perform certain actions, such as opening any File Explorer window, opening the Windows toolbar's options, opening Windows' control panel. Both Firefox and Thunderbird are updated to their latest versions. How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Windows Search Indexing. I solved something similar by turning off indexing of the downloads folder (even though that folder has seemingly nothing to do with Thunderbird).